# Does there getting from $1$ to $\sqrt[4]{2}$ using $\sqrt{\alpha^2+ 1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, totally-real-field

The aim is to get from $1$ to $\sqrt[4]{2}$ or prove it is impossible using only one of the following options:

1. Add or subtract  two previously constructed numbers.
2. Multiply two previously constructed numbers.
3. Using a previously constructed number $\alpha$ construct both solutions to $\alpha^2+1=\beta^2$.
   I’ve managed to construct many numbers close to it, such as $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{2}}$.
   I’m pretty sure it’s impossible but haven’t managed to prove it.
   Can any of you help?
   **Edit 1: reciprocals**
   We can construct all quadratic radicals and rational numbers.
   In this case, we are seaching for an extension of $\mathbb Q$ that is closed under (3), The constructible numbers are closed under this operation, but i think there is a subfield of the constructible numbers closed under it and containing $\mathbb Q$ as a subfield.

Comment: you are likely correct. Hartshorne gives $  \sqrt{   1 + \sqrt 2   }$ as an impossible number. Likely to need Galois Theory to prove impossibility  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_field

Comment: Norm considerations might be useful here. Note that the $\beta$ you construct will always have norm strictly larger than the $\alpha$ you use to construct it. $\alpha = -1,0,1$ construct $\beta = \sqrt{2},1,\sqrt{2}$ respectively. Every other constructible number using steps (1) and (2) (and thus (3)) has norm larger than $\sqrt{2}$. But your number has norm smaller than $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Explaining why this might be important could help to interest others. Until then: good luck with *your* problem.

Comment: How are the norm considerations effected by the ability to add and subtract constructed numbers?

Comment: not clear to me that your game allows reciprocals. Suggest you see if anything changes when allowing reciprocals and division.

Comment: $\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{2}}$ is constructable but its norm/absolute value is smaller than $\sqrt[4]{2}.$ But there might be some other norm where this is true.

Comment: @WillJagy, edited to address your suggestion, it is possible using reciprocals.

Comment: @WillJagy, It was a problem posed by a friend of mine, I'm unsure if he actually solved it.

Comment: razivo  your final calculation is in error, $\sqrt{4 - 2 \sqrt 2   }$ divided by $\sqrt 2$ is $\sqrt{2 -  \sqrt 2   }$

Comment: @WillJagy, I've tried again and haven't found any, so the use of galois theory is probably necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, you should check your calculation again. If you really did construct $2^{1/4}$ you would immediately be able to construct $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt 2}.$  This is not possible: the quickest way to say it is that Hilbert's field is the set of totally real elements in the constructible field (closed under square roots of positive elements).

This is pages 145-148 in *Geometry: Euclid and Beyond* by Robin Hartshorne.

I repeated the first example search at
https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/totallyreal_rel.html

and got

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ sage
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath Version 6.9, Release Date: 2015-10-10                     │
│ Type "notebook()" for the browser-based notebook interface.        │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
sage:  ZZx = ZZ['x']
sage:  F.<t> = NumberField(x^2-2)
sage: enumerate_totallyreal_fields_rel(F, 2, 10000)
[[1600, x^4 - 6*x^2 + 4, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 3*t - 3],
 [2048, x^4 - 4*x^2 + 2, xF^2 + t - 2],
 [2304, x^4 - 4*x^2 + 1, xF^2 + t*xF - 1],
 [2624, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 1],
 [4352, x^4 - 6*x^2 - 4*x + 2, xF^2 + t*xF + t - 2],
 [7168, x^4 - 6*x^2 + 7, xF^2 + t - 3],
 [7232, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 5*x^2 + 4*x + 4, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 2],
 [8768, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 5*x^2 + 6*x + 7, xF^2 + xF + t - 3],
 [9792, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 7*x^2 + 2*x + 7, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 2*t - 3]]



sage: enumerate_totallyreal_fields_rel(F, 2, 100000)
[[1600, x^4 - 6*x^2 + 4, xF^2 + xF - 1],
 [2048, x^4 - 4*x^2 + 2, xF^2 + t - 10],
 [2304, x^4 - 4*x^2 + 1, xF^2 + t*xF - 1],
 [2624, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 1],
 [4352, x^4 - 6*x^2 - 4*x + 2, xF^2 + t*xF + t - 14],
 [7168, x^4 - 6*x^2 + 7, xF^2 + t - 3],
 [7232, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 5*x^2 + 4*x + 4, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 2],
 [8768, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 5*x^2 + 6*x + 7, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 4*t - 5],
 [9792, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 7*x^2 + 2*x + 7, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 2*t - 3],
 [10304, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 7*x^2 + 8*x + 8, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 3*t - 4],
 [10816, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 9*x^2 + 10*x - 1, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 7*t - 9],
 [12544, x^4 - 8*x^2 + 9, xF^2 + t*xF - 3],
 [13888, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 7*x^2 + 6*x + 9, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 3],
 [14336, x^4 - 8*x^2 + 14, xF^2 + t - 4],
 [16448, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 7*x^2 + 8*x + 14, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 6*t - 8],
 [18432, x^4 - 12*x^2 + 18, xF^2 + 3*t - 6],
 [18496, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 11*x^2 + 12*x + 2, xF^2 + xF - 4],
 [18688, x^4 - 10*x^2 - 4*x + 14, xF^2 + t*xF + t - 4],
 [20032, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 9*x^2 + 10*x + 17, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 5*t - 7],
 [21056, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 11*x^2 + 2*x + 17, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 3*t - 5],
 [21568, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 11*x^2 + 12*x + 18, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 4*t - 6],
 [22592, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 9*x^2 + 8*x + 16, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 4],
 [22784, x^4 - 12*x^2 - 8*x + 17, xF^2 + t*xF + 2*t - 5],
 [23552, x^4 - 10*x^2 + 23, xF^2 + t - 5],
 [24832, x^4 - 14*x^2 - 12*x + 18, xF^2 + t*xF + 3*t - 6],
 [26176, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 9*x^2 + 10*x + 23, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 8*t - 11],
 [28224, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 13*x^2 + 14*x + 7, xF^2 + xF - 5],
 [29248, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 11*x^2 + 6*x + 23, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 2*t - 5],
 [30976, x^4 - 12*x^2 + 25, xF^2 + t*xF - 5],
 [31744, x^4 - 14*x^2 + 31, xF^2 + 3*t - 7],
 [31808, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 11*x^2 + 12*x + 28, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 7*t - 10],
 [33344, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 11*x^2 + 10*x + 25, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 5],
 [34816, x^4 - 12*x^2 + 34, xF^2 + t - 6],
 [35392, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 13*x^2 + 14*x + 31, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 6*t - 9],
 [36416, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 15*x^2 + 2*x + 31, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 4*t - 7],
 [36928, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 15*x^2 + 16*x + 32, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 5*t - 8],
 [37952, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 11*x^2 + 12*x + 34, xF^2 + xF + t - 6],
 [41216, x^4 - 14*x^2 - 4*x + 34, xF^2 + t*xF + t - 6],
 [42048, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 13*x^2 + 8*x + 34, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 2*t - 6],
 [45632, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 13*x^2 + 14*x + 41, xF^2 + xF + 2*t - 7],
 [46144, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 13*x^2 + 12*x + 36, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 6],
 [47104, x^4 - 16*x^2 + 46, xF^2 + 3*t - 8],
 [48128, x^4 - 14*x^2 + 47, xF^2 + t - 7],
 [48704, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 15*x^2 + 6*x + 41, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 3*t - 7],
 [49408, x^4 - 16*x^2 - 8*x + 41, xF^2 + t*xF + 2*t - 7],
 [51200, x^4 - 20*x^2 + 50, xF^2 + 5*t - 10],
 [51264, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 15*x^2 + 16*x + 46, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 8*t - 12],
 [51776, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 13*x^2 + 14*x + 47, xF^2 + xF + t - 7],
 [53312, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 17*x^2 + 4*x + 46, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 4*t - 8],
 [53824, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 17*x^2 + 18*x + 23, xF^2 + xF - 7],
 [54848, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 17*x^2 + 18*x + 49, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 7*t - 11],
 [55552, x^4 - 18*x^2 - 12*x + 46, xF^2 + t*xF + 3*t - 8],
 [55872, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 2*x + 49, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 5*t - 9],
 [56384, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 20*x + 50, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 6*t - 10],
 [56896, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 15*x^2 + 10*x + 47, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 2*t - 7],
 [57600, x^4 - 16*x^2 + 49, xF^2 + t*xF - 7],
 [59648, x^4 - 20*x^2 - 16*x + 49, xF^2 + t*xF + 4*t - 9],
 [60992, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 15*x^2 + 14*x + 49, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 7],
 [61696, x^4 - 22*x^2 - 20*x + 50, xF^2 + t*xF + 5*t - 10],
 [63488, x^4 - 16*x^2 + 62, xF^2 + t - 8],
 [64512, x^4 - 18*x^2 + 63, xF^2 + 3*t - 9],
 [65600, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 17*x^2 + 8*x + 56, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 3*t - 8],
 [67648, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 15*x^2 + 16*x + 62, xF^2 + xF + t - 8],
 [69184, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 17*x^2 + 18*x + 63, xF^2 + xF + 3*t - 9],
 [69696, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 20*x + 34, xF^2 + xF - 8],
 [71936, x^4 - 18*x^2 - 4*x + 62, xF^2 + t*xF + t - 8],
 [72256, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 6*x + 63, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 4*t - 9],
 [72704, x^4 - 22*x^2 + 71, xF^2 + 5*t - 11],
 [73792, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 17*x^2 + 12*x + 62, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 2*t - 8],
 [74816, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 20*x + 68, xF^2 + xF + 4*t - 10],
 [76864, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 21*x^2 + 4*x + 68, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 5*t - 10],
 [77888, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 17*x^2 + 16*x + 64, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 8],
 [79424, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 23*x^2 + 2*x + 71, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 6*t - 11],
 [79424, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 17*x^2 + 18*x + 73, xF^2 + xF + 2*t - 9],
 [79936, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 23*x^2 + 24*x + 72, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 7*t - 12],
 [80896, x^4 - 18*x^2 + 79, xF^2 + t - 9],
 [83968, x^4 - 20*x^2 + 82, xF^2 + 3*t - 10],
 [84224, x^4 - 20*x^2 - 8*x + 73, xF^2 + t*xF + 2*t - 9],
 [84544, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 10*x + 73, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 3*t - 9],
 [85568, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 17*x^2 + 18*x + 79, xF^2 + xF + t - 9],
 [87616, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 21*x^2 + 22*x + 47, xF^2 + xF - 9],
 [89152, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 20*x + 82, xF^2 + xF + 3*t - 10],
 [92416, x^4 - 20*x^2 + 81, xF^2 + t*xF - 9],
 [92736, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 14*x + 79, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 2*t - 9],
 [93248, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 21*x^2 + 8*x + 82, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 4*t - 10],
 [94464, x^4 - 22*x^2 - 12*x + 82, xF^2 + t*xF + 3*t - 10],
 [96256, x^4 - 24*x^2 + 94, xF^2 + 5*t - 12],
 [96832, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 18*x + 81, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + t - 9],
 [96832, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 21*x^2 + 22*x + 89, xF^2 + xF + 4*t - 11],
 [99392, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 19*x^2 + 20*x + 92, xF^2 + xF + 2*t - 10],
 [99904, x^4 - 2*x^3 - 23*x^2 + 6*x + 89, xF^2 + (t + 1)*xF + 5*t - 11]]
sage:
```

Comment: I do not understand fully what you mean, $\sqrt{1+\sqrt 2}$ is constructible, and I haven't been able to find information related about hilbert's field.

Comment: @razivo  As far as I  can tell, the calculation that says that $\mathbb Q[\alpha],$  as with $\alpha^4 - 2 = 0,$  is not totally real is simply the observation that two roots of $x^4 - 2$ are imaginary.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_field

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_real_number_field  I did ask Jyrki to look at this question, he has answered questions about totally real fields.

Comment: @razivo looked up some things, you will be able to construct $\sqrt{ 2 \pm \sqrt 2}$ but not $\sqrt{  \sqrt 2  \pm 1}$