# Representation theory

Tags: representation-theory

I want to know if this is true or not, and if yes how we can prove it.
Given a group G and a map p be a 2- dimensional representation of G in to GL(2,ℂ).
If there exist g, h ∈ G such that the matrices p(g) and p(h) do not commute then the representation p is irreducible.

Comment: Is the group known to be finite? What do you know about the diagonalizability of commuting matrices? What do you know about commutation of diagonal matrices?

Comment: Also, I recommend that you take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Your question is a little short of context.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you please take a look at 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926383/does-there-getting-from-1-to-sqrt42-using-sqrt-alpha2-1  I gave an answer I believe is correct, but I don't know anywhere near enough to be convincing.